# How to lock google sheet from myself - well from the the owner really

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I created a complicated Google sheet to track shooting training and performance and I want to release it to the world. The thing is, I want to make sure nobody breaks it.

One way is to keep the file mine and make a copy for everyone who wants it - not really scalable.

The other way that I see is to get a script to lock the ranges even for the owner, cos I will let everyone to make their own copy. The only trouble with this preferred option is that I don't even know if it's possible.

Does anybody know how to do that or maybe some other way around this issue?

Comment: Please avoid profanity, even if you write it l1k3 th1$.

Comment: Also, please take the [tour] and read about what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions.

Comment: May I ask: 1) `and I want to release it to the world` - do you want to release it for free or would there be a fee/charge? 2) `not really scalable` - what do you mean by scalable in this context? 3) `I want to make sure nobody breaks it` - do you mean that someone might break _your_ copy or _their_ copy?